# Huge delay of scrolling images

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using rssFeed to load url image with following code. However, once images loaded into iPhone, there was huge delay of scrolling. I have been googling for solutions. Besides, changing to LazyImageLoad, is any easier solution that can fix my issue?? Thank you.

```
    NSString *imageURLString = [rssFeed objectForKey:@img"];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the images on a separate thread not on the ui thread. Is your choice if you download on demand or if you do a cashing algorithm.

And you should resize the images to a small size (preferable the size of your imageView) and then assign them to the imageView. In the table view you should only see an preview of the image.

If you want fast scrolling you have to build your own custom cell (not xib) by subclassing UITableViewCell and draw everything in the drawContentView.